# Using OAuth in a C# command line application

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, console-application

Using code that works in an Azure App Service, I am attempting to get an OAuth access token in a command line application.

This is my code:

```
IConfidentialClientApplication app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(clientId)
                .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
                .WithAuthority(new Uri(authority))
                .Build();

string accessToken ="";

try
{
    AuthenticationResult authResult = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
    accessToken = authResult.AccessToken;
}
catch (MsalServiceException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Service error occurred: {ex.Message}");
}
catch (MsalClientException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Client error occurred: {ex.Message}");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"An unexpected error occurred: {ex.Message}");
}
```

It exits with no error on the `AcquireTokenForClient` method call. I don't understand why execution terminates. No error is thrown, and the return code is zero. If I'm barking up the wrong tree, OK. I am open to suggestions. I need the access token so I can use it with an exchange web service object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out my whole problem was that I was using an async method, which was spawning a new thread and exiting the application.  I dropped the async keyword from the method and changed

AuthenticationResult authResult = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();

to

AuthenticationResult authResult = app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync().Result;

And now, there is much rejoicing...

Looks like I have a lot to learn...but what's life without growth?

Answer (score -1):

All the sample codes from Azure App Service assume that you have web application, and web application always uses authentication flow type of either implicit or hybrid, and both of them require to redirect to OAuth sign-in page which is then redirected back to the app after sign in.

For console app, you cannot use the sample code as is, as you need additional/different flow type.
Please check the sample app of this on this GitHub:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-console-up-v2

Comment: This code works in a web service application, exactly as it is.  I am trying to understand why it fails in a console app.